# Major fallacy in accepted manuscript

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript around two months ago. The reviewers gave me generally good comments, and the editor suggested "minor revision".

Problem is, I think the main part of my manuscript have a big problem. I am currently making further readings into the subject and delving deeper into the math. All previous research suggest that I am giving an incomplete solution, resulting eventually in an inaccurate simulation.

Although I have a large mistake in the manuscript. This mistake if corrected will support my results even more (Lucky me).

I will tell the editor of course about the mistake, but I need time to correct my simulation, manuscript etc...

My questions are:

1- Can I ask the editor form more time?

2- Will the editor reject my paper because it have a major mistake?

Comment: "This mistake if corrected will support my results even more (Lucky me)." Don't get into these quick conclusions. Just withdraw the paper, giving editor the reason being fallacy and work on it leisurely and carefully. At some later point of time, if results really support without any fallacy, then resubmit choosing an appropriate journal.

Comment: This way you will save from more potential embarrasment.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Absolutely. I was thinking of asking the editor for another round of revision, but without withdrawing my manuscript. Because as you said, one cannot be sure of anything. Would that be possible? (I forgot to ask this in the main post). I am basically asking for "major revision" I guess!

Comment: It is not that clear what would be the pro of an extension. If I would be the editor I would say yes, but the paper will be subjected to a new round of revision. I think all they do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are yes and yes. But for most purposes more like yes and unlikely.

You can ask for time. It may be possible to get time or not. For a conference it is harder, of course, especially when there is some uncertainty about when it will really be finished. For a journal asking for time might cause minor disruption, but it would likely only result in getting published in a later issue of the journal.

But the editor can also ask that the paper be withdrawn and resubmitted when it is complete. That is up to them. If they thought the paper was originally good, then they are more likely to work with you.

And be sure to indicate that the paper will be improved, not just corrected.

Comment: So, I should be positive while asking for an extension. Also, I need to point that I am improving the paper drastically instead of just saying that I discovered a major mistake.

Comment: Positive, yes, but don't neglect to also say there is an error.